# Execute a function which is located inside another function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am creating a web app in **MVC with Javascript** in which i have a function which look like the following

```
function test() {
   //this function won't do anything but create a new function inside.
     function executeLot(lot1, lot2) {
       //normal function execution;
     }
}
```

now i want to call the function `executeLot(1,2)`
but i am not able to call this as it is located inside `test()`

what can i do to call executeLot from outside of the test function.

Comment: You can easily implement in this way.
`function test() {
   //this function won't do anything but create a new function inside.
 executeLot(lot1, lot2);
}
function executeLot(lot1, lot2) {
       //normal function execution;
 }
`

Comment: Give more epxlanation! Did you use this function only like simple method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for your MVC platform is class model based system not global methods or procedurally code.

See example :

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class Definition ECMA 5 - works on all modern browsers 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function Test() {

     this.executeLot = function(lot1, lot2) {
       //normal function execution;
       console.log(lot1 + " <> " + lot2)
     }
     
}

//////////////////////////////////
// Make instance from this class
//////////////////////////////////

var myTest = new Test();

//////////////////////////////////
// Call method
//////////////////////////////////
myTest.executeLot(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function directly. You will have to return it like this:

```
function test() {
  return function executeLot(lot1, lot2) {
    // [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: for God's shake NO NO NO

Comment: @ManosKounelakis I'm assuming you are talking about the latter version? Yes it is rather ugly and I should probably remove it. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Yeah I am talking about the latest version

Comment: inside test you assign executeLoot to myFunction

Comment: check again the body of the test function in your 2nd code

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Oh what the heck was wrong with me when I wrote that oO... Thanks for pointing that out :) I'm just gonna remove it

Answer (score 0):

You could return a function and assign it into a variable like this:

```
function test(){
    return function(arg1,arg2){
        // do your magic here
    }
}

var executeLoot = test();
//Call your returned function
var arg1 = 1;
var arg2 = 2;
executeLoot(arg1,arg2);
```